# fetching data from three tables in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

The is the table structure,which basically has three tables,namely expenses,categories and sunbcategories

```
table expenses
(id,category_id,sub_category_id,date,description,amount)
table categories
(id,category_name)
table subcategories
(id,sub_category_name,category_id)
```

This is the SQL query that is needed

```
select expense.date, expense.description, expense.amount, 
category.category_name, subcategory.sub_category_name
from expenses as expense,categories as category,subcategories as subcategory
where expense.category_id=category.id and
    category.id=subcategory.category_id);
```

This is the function in Expense model with which I pass the category_id
The same query mentioned above is written in laravel, but I am not able to 
fetch the data.

```
function fetchExpenseData($categoryId)
{
    $expense = Expense::select("expenses.*","categories.category_name as 
    Categoryname","subcategories.Sub_category_name")
        ->join("categories","categories.id","=","expenses.category_id");
        ->join("subcategories",function($join)
        {
            $join>on("subcategories.category_id","=","expenses.category_id")
                ->on("suncategories.id","=","expenses.sub_category_id")
        })->get();
    return $expenses;
}
```

$expenses that are returned will be printed in blade.php.
Can I know what is the mistake

thanks in advance

Comment: typo on `$join>on(` , update it and let us know if you still not get o/p

Comment: still not getting the data, is the query wrong

Comment: Are you aware that your Laravel code has one _extra_ join condition in it, which the raw MySQL query does not have?  Which version of the query do you really want to be using here?

Comment: your sql do not have `$join->on("subcategories.category_id","=", 
                      "expenses.category_id")` this condition, and also you haven't used `$categoryId`

Comment: Jigar,can I know the alternative

Comment: Tim, I am using laravel 5.4

Comment: does any one the answer???

Answer (score 0):

```
Hye there , 
You need to add eloquent model for retrieving data fromenter code here three tables
Like 
I have School Table , Student Table , Teacher Table
School is relating with both Student and Teacher then we will add relationship
In School Model 
`
public function getStudent(){
  return $this->hasMany('student_id' , App\Student);
}

public function getTeachers(){
  return $this->hasMany('teacher_id' , App\Teacher);
}

In Student table
public function getSchool(){
 return $this->hasOne('school_id' , App\School);
}
`
now call data from student
`
$students = Student::with('getSchool.getTeachers')->get()

This Demonstration for  what I have get from your Question
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Is the printing format same in this case and do you have any idea of how to fetch it based on a particular ID

Comment: yeah , not much same format but it is well organized rather than query builder in sql